# What do series values stand for in Prometheus unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, prometheus

I am trying to understand what series values stand for in Prometheus unit test.

The [official doc](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/unit_testing_rules/) does not provide any info.

For example, fire an alert if any instance is down over 10 seconds.

**alerting-rules.yml**

```
groups:
  - name: alert_rules
    rules:
      - alert: InstanceDown
        expr: up == 0
        for: 10s
        labels:
          severity: critical
        annotations:
          summary: "Instance {{ $labels.instance }} down"
          description: "{{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for more than 10 seconds."
```

**alerting-rules.test.yml**

```
rule_files:
  - alerting-rules.yml

evaluation_interval: 1m

tests:
  - interval: 1m
    input_series:
      - series: 'up{job="prometheus", instance="localhost:9090"}'
        values: '0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'
    alert_rule_test:
      - eval_time: 10m
        alertname: InstanceDown
        exp_alerts:
          - exp_labels:
              severity: critical
              instance: localhost:9090
              job: prometheus
            exp_annotations:
              summary: "Instance localhost:9090 down"
              description: "localhost:9090 of job prometheus has been down for more than 10 seconds."
```

Originally, I thought because of `interval: 1m`, which is 60 seconds, and there are 15 numbers, 60 / 15 = 4s, so each value stands for 4 seconds (1 means up, 0 means down).

However, when the values are

```
values: '0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'
```

or

```
values: '1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0'
```

Both will pass the test when I run `promtool test rules alerting-rules.test.yml`.

But below will fail:

```
values: '1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0'
```

So my original thought each number stands for 4s is wrong. If my assumption is correct, then only when less three `0`s will fail the test.

What do series values stand for in Prometheus unit test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrrect. The number in the values doesn't correspond at the number of value in the interval but which value the series will have after each interval. For example:

```
 values: 1  1  1  1  1  1
    #    1m 2m 3m 4m 5m 6m
```

In your example, since you evaluate the value at 10min (with *eval_time*) the evaluation will be based on the tenth value in the *values*. Since you check if *up==0*, when you change the tenth value to 1 it will fail because the alert will not be trigger as excepted.